# Precompiled javascript files do not work after heroku deployment, is there a good js files order?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have noticed something weird. In local machine, in that order of javascript files, modernizr.custom is working (showing menu in smartphone version) but components-style and icheck are not working. If I try design just below components-style, components-style is working and not modernizr.custom.
I can't figure why. Is that a precise order of javascript files?

```
//= require modernizr.custom
//= require jquery.easing.1.3
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require cocoon
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require social-share-button
//= require jquery.validate
//= require design
//= require components-styles
//= require icheck.min
//= require jquery.touchSwipe.min
//= require respond.min
//= require jquery.bxslider.min
//= require jquery.fitvids
//= require jquery.placeholder
//= require smoothscroll
//= require waypoints.min
//= require jquery.bootstrap.wizard
//= require excanvas
//= require_tree .
```

Second issue. When I deploy on heroku, components-style, icheck and modernizr are not working.

My application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Production.rb :

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

I have tried `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`, and I have found all javascrit in public/assets in application-xxx.js
But after deplying on heroku, modernizr.custom and components-style do not work (maybe others too).

I have tried adding `config.assets.precompile << '*.js'` in assets.rb and production.rb and then precompiling. Same result.

gemfile:

```
ruby "2.3.0"

gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem "friendly_id", "~> 5.0.1"
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 4.0'
gem 'social-share-button', '~> 0.1.6'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem "cocoon"
gem 'counter_culture', '~> 0.1.23'
gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'puma'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

I have tried many things I've found here but it is still not working. I really need this website working on smartphone.

I can not find a fix, thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove //require_tree as it'll recursively load all js files but not the order you specified.

Comment: I don't know if the order I specified is the good one. I try removing //require_tree but it does not change anything both locally and on heroku  :/

Comment: Did you check asset.precompile=true in production.rb file.

Comment: Do you mean config.assets.compile = true ? I have this line.
I have tried config.assets.precompile = true right now. Error when I deploy on heroku

Comment: Ok,Would you check the ordering of require js files.Library files at the top and custom js files at the bottom. You could check using inspect in web browser if any javascript files is failing to load.

Comment: Good point, that works on heroku. I get my menu on smartphone :)
Thanks a lot Waliul !

Do u think that is the same point for components style/icheck that do not work cuz of the order? This issue is not as important as the other. But I'm curious to understand

Comment: maybe.Are you working with Google Grid Gallery - Tympanus? I worked with this grid layout and moderizer was not found. You must check browser console to check if all javascript files are loaded properly.If some file is dependent on other files then place it at the bottom.Let me know if this works.I'll be glad to help you.

Comment: That's great, the problem was with design.js and component-styles.js. They have few common lines of code ^^ my bad